# Pointer to unique_ptr - is this a loophole?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

It seems an easy way to circumvent a `unique_ptr` is to use a pointer to the `unique_ptr` object. And that's not difficult. So using the unique_ptr is sort of a gentleman's agreement and not really super enforced?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Box {
  public:
    int num;
};

void update_box(unique_ptr<Box>* pu);

int main(){
  unique_ptr<Box> b{new Box};
  unique_ptr<Box>* u = &b;
  update_box(u);
  cout << b->num << endl; // Outputs 99.
  return 0;
}

void update_box(unique_ptr<Box>* pu) {
  (*pu)->num = 99;
}
```

Comment: What piece of the contract do you think you are circumventing here?

Comment: Your example shows that you can pass a `unique_ptr` by pointer (or reference) to a function and modify the object that it points to. Why shouldn't you be able to do this?

Comment: Having a unique ptr does not mean that you are not allowed to pass it or its pointer to somewhere else, it just says who is the owner of that pointer and responsible for the lifetime of the object it is pointing to. So you could write `void update_box(const unique_ptr<Box> &pu);` and you would be able to use `pui->num = 99` in that function. Or you could pass it as raw pointer `u->get()`.

Comment: In many cases the smart pointers should not be looked at like a simple self-deleting pointer, but in terms of *ownership*. Sometimes you want a single ownership of a "resource" so you use `std::unique_ptr`. And sometimes you want others to use the resource without passing on the ownership, which can be done by passing a pointer or *reference* to the `std::unique_ptr` object.

Comment: @hellow: Yes it will. A `unique_ptr<T> const&` is not a ``unique_ptr<const T> const&`. Entirely unrelated types, in afct.

Comment: can you please explain what is wrong about this example? I dont get it ...

Comment: @user463035818 - My understanding of `unique_ptr` is that it should be used to ensure you only have one pointer to an object at any time. But by using a pointer to the `unique_ptr` it seems like I now have multiple pointers.

Comment: @PlastyGrove no thats not what a `unique_ptr` is for, at least to my understanding. You can have as many pointers as you like, but only one of them owns the instance and `unique_ptr` helps you to realize that

Comment: @StoryTeller - The contract I was expecting was that there's no way to have more than one pointer to the object if I use `unique_ptr`. I guess I haven't used C++ enough yet.

Comment: @Plasty_Grove The whole idea is that you only have one pointer that owns the dynamically-allocated `Box` object. As such, when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, the `Box` will be safely `delete`d. Having a raw pointer to the `unique_ptr` does not change this fact.

Comment: pointers arent really the problem that smart pointers solve, its ownership that they manage, ie who is responsible for deleting the instance

Comment: Even if getting a pointer to the `std::unique_ptr` object, you still only have a single pointer to the pointer wrapped by the `std::unique_ptr` object. You can have as many pointers or references to the `std::unique_ptr` object as you want, but there will still be only one `std::unique_ptr` object.

Comment: btw I am not aware of any mechanism in C++ to disable taking the adress of something (you can overload `operator*` but you cant overload `addressof`)

Comment: @PlastyGrove unique pointer does not mean that there should only be one pointer to that object. It says something about the ownership. For an `unique_prt`  you have only one owner that is responsible and connected to the lifetime of the object. You are allowed to have e.g. one-to-many relations using unique_ptr to the child and raw pointer (or [std::experimental::observer_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr)) to the parent. But its your responsibility that the raw  (observer pointer) is always valid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You actually put your real question into a comment:

> My understanding of `unique_ptr` is that it should be used to ensure you only have one pointer to an object at any time.

No, this is wrong. You can easily do a simple:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int);
int *b = a.get(); // b points to the same object as a
```

The design of `unique_ptr` *tries* to ensure that you can only have one **`unique_ptr`** to an object. But even, it can ensure this only if you don't use naked pointers. With naked pointers, it is easy to sidestep this design:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int);
std::unique_ptr<int> b(a.get());
```

Here, `b` points to the same object as `a`, so this program has undefined behavior (because the `int` object will be deleted twice).

`unique_ptr`'s intent is to show **ownership**. As there can be only one `unique_ptr` which can point to an object (ignoring the "hack" I've presented earlier), `unique_ptr` owns the pointed object, and as `unique_ptr`'s destructor is called, it will delete the pointed object.

Comment: Wow - this is insane. Shows I really don't know anything about C++ :|. I didn't realise `unique_ptr` has a `.get()` function.

Comment: @PlastyGrove actually `int* b = new int; std::unique_ptr<int> a(b);` is valid, no `.get` needed.

Comment: @appleapple  `int* b = new int; std::unique_ptr<int> a(b);` is valid, but is - imho - kind of an antipattern. At least you can get used to something that might become problematic. E.g. if you would start to write something like `int* b1 = new int; int* b2 = new int; std::unique_ptr<int> a1(b1); std::unique_ptr<int> a2(b2);`  you might have a problem with exception safety. So a `std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int); int* b = a.get()` is preferable. I would always use the `new` in the initialization of the _smart pointers_ , as then the ownership and intended usage are clear, at its initialization.

Comment: @t.niese I'd say then it's better to use [make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). I'm just extending this answer (and reply to op's comment).

Comment: will `unique_ptr` consider gotten pointer into its lifecycle?

Answer (score 18):

C++ is, in a sense, full of gentlemen's agreements. In other words, the language gives you the ability to shoot yourself in the foot.

There is nothing to prevent you taking the address of a `std::unique_ptr`. If you *really* find that distasteful then you could inherit from `std::unique_ptr` and overload the address-of operator with a function containing a static assertion.

But even if you did that, you could circumvent that with `std::addressof`!

Comment: The whole of programming is full of gentlemen's agreements, really. Communication protocols? API's? ABI's?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Absolutely. Which is why these days programming is a vocation for a gentleman: beats the clergy anyway.

Comment: Pays better on average too.

Comment: @StoryTeller: These days yes although back in the early 1800s a good living could approach £1000 per year with accommodation all paid for. Difficult to speculate what a programmer would have earned in the 1800s though.

Comment: What would the gentlemen's agreement be in this case?

Comment: English is not my primary language, and I didn't know the expression [gentlemen's agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentlemen%27s_agreement). It defines computer science pretty well actually.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is answered by multiple people. But what I want to mention is that, there could be real usecase where you need to pass reference of unique_ptr.

Consider the below example :

```
StatusMsg getMemory(unique_ptr<char[]>& Up) {
   unique_ptr<char[]> mem(new char[100]);
   Up = std::move(mem);
   return StatusMsg::Success;
}

int main() {
   unique_ptr<char[]> Up;
   StatusMsg s = getMemory(Up);
   if (s!=StatusMsg::Success) {
     // throw error
   }
   
   // Do something with allocated memory
}
```

Here the unique_ptr must be returned (or updated) using call by reference, since the actual return value should be the status msg.

Comment: See for instance one of my older questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720204/vector-with-references-to-unique-ptr) where I had a similar use case (a vector with constant references to uniqe_ptr)